# How can you tell where your solution is opened from?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a VB.net solution that I made a complete copy of and placed on a different drive and now I cannot tell which solution I have been working in.

Is there a way I can tell where my solution was opened from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Solution Explorer pane, right click your Project (e.g., WindowsApplication1), and select "Open Folder in Windows Explorer" from the menu that pops up. That way you can see the actual directory it is stored in.

Answer (score 2):

When the Project is selected in the Solution Explorer, you can see the full path of the containing folder in the Misc > Project Folder property in the Properties pane.

<kbd>F4</kbd> will display the Properties pane if it is not visible.

For a Solution, the Misc > Path property shows its full path.

And, similarly, the Misc > Full Path property shows a file's full path.

And emphasising these Properties are only valid when the Solution Explorer was the last pane that was active.

Answer (score 0):

You can also hover over the project name in the recent items in the Start page: that will show the project's full path on the status bar.